# Jupyter notebook process freezes on startup

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter on several platforms, but for some reason, I can no longer get it to start on Windows 10.

Starting jupyter notebook with the `--debug` flag, returns the following information:

[image: jupyter notebook]

The output freezes at that point, no browser is started and tried to open `http://localhost:8888` returns no response. The process also does not react to `CTRL-C`, it has to be killed.

I've tried the following:

- regenerated (overwritten) the config file with the default settings.
- completely re-installed Python and jupyter libraries.
- tried starting `jupyter notebook`, `jupyter lab` and `jupyter-notebook`.

Looking at the process list, I can see `jupyter-notebook.exe` and associated process are started.

[image: process list]

I can also see that the child `python.exe` process is listening on port `8888`.

[image: process tcp/ip]

The output for `jupyter troubleshoot` is available [here](https://pastebin.com/5d6xE75E) (too exhaustive to paste).

Comment: As you may already know, you can directly launch jupyter by `python jupyter.py notebook`. Further you can use `pdb` to debug this process `python -m pdb jupyter.py notebook`. It may help.

Comment: If you think it is awful, you can use some ide to debug it such as `Pycharm`. Just setup up the running configuration to `jupyter notebook` and place breakpoint in corresponding file. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I compared the output to a working environment, and found that after the point where it freezes, jupyter normally loads the extensions. So I performed the following command:

```
jupyter nbextension list
```

which returns:

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: c:\dev\venv\jupyter\etc\jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled
      - Validating: ok
```

I then tried to disable the extension using `jupyter nbextension disable jupyter-js-widgets`.

Running `jupyter nbextension list` again now results in the following output:

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: C:\Users\Admin\.jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets disabled
  config dir: c:\dev\venv\jupyter\etc\jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled
      - Validating: ok
```

Jupyter notebook now works again, but I don't know yet what the impact is of having to disable the extension or why it certainly became an issue.